# Draw 2 or More Features with 1 Draw Interaction

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-7

Our application draws 3 geometries: centerLine, centerToEdgesLines, boundaryPolygon (in 1 geometry collection)

Is it possible to use Openlayers Draw interaction (LineString) to draw 3 Features instead ?

This is to make Modify interaction easier to code, so users can modify centerLine, centerToEdgesLines, boundaryPolygon separately.

With 1 GeometryCollection, not sure how to determine if user clicks on centerToEdgesLines or boundary as they are all in 1 geometry collection

[image]

However looking at https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/interaction/Draw.js#L1496
only 1 Feature is created.

```
this.sketchFeature_ = new Feature();
```

Short of extending ol.interaction.Draw , is there another way to get Draw interaction to create multiple features at one go ?

[image]